# About url rewrite with query string

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

Please help, how to make this url
(in my request i use get function)

**iplookup.php?lookup_ip=66.249.66.1**

to looks like this?

**/ip/66.249.66.1**

with

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lookup_ip=
RewriteRule ^ip/(.*)$ iplookup.php?lookup_ip=$1 [QSA]
```

But unsuccessful :(

Comment: Have you inserted `RewriteEngine On` in the starting of .htaccess if no then put it.

Comment: yes already do it :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the condition. The `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lookup_ip=` condition is only true if `lookup_ip=` is in the query string, and obviously the URI `/ip/66.249.66.1` doesn't have one. Your rule should just look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^ip/(.*)$ /iplookup.php?lookup_ip=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then when you request `http://yourdomain.com/ip/12.34.56.78`, the browser's URL address bar remains unchanged while you get served the content at `/iplookup.php?lookup_ip=12.34.56.78`. You just need to make sure all of your links look like `http://yourdomain.com/ip/12.34.56.78`.

Comment: but when try to lookup aditional ip it shows

/ip/?lookup_ip=66.249.66.2

My form is
<form action="/ip/" method="get">
<input type="text" value="{$address}" name="lookup_ip" id="lookup_ip">
<input type="submit" value="IP Lookup"/>
</form>

Is it possible to hide "?lookup_ip=" now